# High School Acoustics Experiment

Tags: acoustics

Is there a way to measure the sound intensity of the sound produced from a speaker without using the sound level meter? I just am curious how we can maybe measure such intensities of sound without using a sound meter. Because in most high school experiments it seems like they just automatically assume we take these decibels recorded on the sound level meter as granted without actually measuring these intensity  levels ourselves.

Comment: What do you mean by "measuring ourselves"? You don't want to use any instrument at all? Just by ear?

Comment: Well, you can use a very responsive pressure meter, but why making it complicated?

Comment: @FGSUZ very responsive pressure meters don't have to be expensive. They are called "microphones." But you might need to calibrate them, since the cheap ones are more nonlinear than the expensive ones.

Comment: Wouldn't anything you do to figure this out really just be a manual "sound level meter"?  Do you know a method that's more "direct" than the one they use?

Comment: Was wondering if there is any way to measure intensity other than the standard sound meter we have in high school labs these days

Comment: Short answer: No. Measurement requires some calibrated measurement device. What's wrong with the "standard sound meter?" Are you assuming it's wrong. Get a second one and compare the two.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Any way you come up with will still rely on other measuring devices.  Without a really complicated setup, it also seems unlikely you would be anywhere near as accurate as something pre-packaged to measure sound intensity.

Answer (score 1):

the cheap but rough method has been to point the loudspeaker vertically upwards and sprinkle some dry sand on the cone, then turn on the sound. the height to which the sand particles bounce is a rough measure of the loudness of the sound.